# Adding multiple actions on button generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I've generated buttons dynamically. I would like to add a click and onInputOver actions to this button, but only the `click(chooseHero)` button works:

**EDIT FULL_CODE**

```
var heroesState = {
  create: function() {
    //game.add.image(0, 0, 'board');
    backBtn = game.add.button(5, 5, 'back_btn', this.GoBack);
    choiceText = game.add.bitmapText(150, 50, 'desyrel', 'Welcome warrior, Choose your Hero', 35);

    //var heroCardStyle = { fill: "#00ff00" };

    var initWidth = 60;
    var initHeight = 150;

    var heroesFiles = ["obatala.jpg", "obba.jpg", "olokun.jpg", "orunmila.jpg", "oshun.jpg",
      "oxosi.jpg", "oya.jpg", "ozain.jpg", "shango.jpg", "yemoja.jpg"
    ];
    var heroesLength = heroesFiles.length;
    var heroCard = [];
    //4 buttons generated dynamically with a loop
    for (var i = 0; i < heroesLength / 2; i++) {
      //longueur de chaque élément dans heroes
      var ln = heroesFiles[i].length;
      heroCard = game.add.button(initWidth, initHeight, heroesFiles[i].substring(0, ln - 4), this.ChooseHero, this.over);
      heroCard.scale.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
      heroCard.alpha = 0.4;
      initWidth = initWidth + 150;
    };

    var initWidth = 60;
    var initHeight = 350;
    //4 buttons generated dynamically with a loop
    for (var i = heroesLength / 2; i < heroesLength; i++) {
      //longueur de chaque élément dans heroes
      var ln = heroesFiles[i].length;
      heroCard = game.add.button(initWidth, initHeight, heroesFiles[i].substring(0, ln - 4), this.ChooseHero, this.over);
      heroCard.scale.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
      heroCard.alpha = 0.4;
      initWidth = initWidth + 150;

    };
    //heroCard.onInputOver.add(over, this); 

  },
  //functions associated to button events(chooseChero works fine but over doesn't work)
  GoBack: function() {
    game.state.start("menu");
  },

  over: function() {
    heroCard.tint = 0xffffff;
  },

  ChooseHero: function() {
    //game.state.start("menu");
    chosenHero = this.key;
    alert(this.key);
    game.state.start("play", true, false, chosenHero);
  }
};
```

I receive this error : **Cannot read property 'onInputOver' of undefined**.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using heroCard and then this.heroCard? What does this. heroCard show when you pause on it in the debug tools?

Comment: I've tried without this and he says "over is not defined"

Comment: You have this.ChooseHero above, have you tried this.over? Is there more to the code than what you are showing?

Comment: I've tried this.over also. Doesn't work. Actually there is more code but i'm convinced the remaining is not related to the problem.

Comment: You might need to provide more code. As it is, Andrew is on the right track. The error is telling you that `this.heroCard` doesn't exist, and then your other is telling you that it can't find `over`. Can you add the code that surrounds these snippets?

Comment: Is this all inside of a revealing module pattern or just a closure?

Comment: I've added the full code snippet

Comment: What does game.add.button return? Is it returning a button? or just adding one.

Answer (score 1):

From the additional code I can see the following issues:

1. `game.add.button()` has a different signature. From [the official docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser-ce/Phaser.Button.html) we can see that it's:

> new Button(game [, x] [, y] [, key] [, callback] [, callbackContext] [, overFrame] [, outFrame] [, downFrame] [, upFrame])

`overFrame`, `outFrame`, `downFrame`, and `upFrame` are all looking for the frame to use on the graphic being used, not for a function to call.

2. `var heroCard = [];` is being used to initialize the variable, but then you're setting this to an actual button. I might recommend changing this to `heroCards` and then create a new `heroCard` in a `for` loop, defining it's properties there before adding it to your `heroCards` array.
3. `heroCard.onInputOver.add(over, this);` should be within your for loop. If you `console.log(arguments);` you can see that you get two arguments back, which lets you use the first one to just modify the button they hover over:

   ```
   over: function(heroCard) {
       heroCard.tint = 0xffffff;
       // This is a quick and dirty way to see what arguments are being passed
       // to a function in JavaScript.
       // console.log(arguments);
   }
   ```